# Blade - Echoing code block loop variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have this blade snippet in a loop, I want to make array of description. How do I echo the value of $i+1 ?

```
{{ Form::text('description[$i]', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Description')) }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>

@for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    {{ Form::text('description['.$i.']', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Description')) }}

    <?php $i++; ?>
@endfor
```

Comment: Well, I forgot to try just 1 more thing and that did it 'description['.$i.']' I forgot to break the string. Thanks for indicating this.